# nodejs postgres x509 auth

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I am trying to figure out how I can use x509 auth to my postgres db through nodejs.

When using standard user/pass the connection works.

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'username',
    host: 'myhostnamehere',
    password: 'passwordhere'
    databse: 'databasenamehere',
    port: port#here,
})
```

I tried using the following, in place of the above. But I think this is more for TLS between client and server to have secure connection and still use user/pass combo.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'username',
    host: 'myhostnamehere',
    databse: 'database',
    port: portnumberhere,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      mode: 'verify-full', 
      ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca/crt').toString(),
      key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key').toString(),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ccrt').toString(),
   },
        port: portnumberhere,
})
```

There are no errors, really. Nothing happens the node runs but I can't get data from the database because the authentication doesn't seem to be taking place.

I *can* connect using x509 using the following:

```
psql 'host=hostnamehere port=portnumberhere dbname=database-name user=username sslmode=verify-full sslcert=path/to/.crt sslkey=path/to/.key sslrootcert=path/to/.crt'
```

Which leads me to think there is a limitation in nodejs to support authenticating to a database using x509 over username/passwd combo. Any guidance is appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: "Nothing happens the node runs but I can't get data from the database because the authentication doesn't seem to be taking place."  This doesn't make any sense.  PostgreSQL doesn't just drop you into a tarpit when authentication fails.  You will get some kind of error.